# Using Jasmine beforeEach asynchronously while passing this.result to test

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await, jasmine, jasmine-node

The following code fails a unit test because this.result is still undefined. Is my issue with variable scope, asynchronous behavior, or something else I haven't thought of? My end goal is to pass this test where `this.result == "somevalue"`

```
describe("This is a test", ()=> {
  beforeEach(async ()=> {
    this.result = await "somevalue";
  })

  it("should be somevalue", async ()=> {
    await this.result;
    expect(this.result).toBe("somevalue")
  })
});
```

Edit: I tried the following and got it to work, however is there a way to pass this.[some variable] as we see in the Jasmine documentation for using `beforeEach()`?

```
describe("This is a test", ()=> {
  let result = undefined;
  beforeEach(async ()=> {
    result = await "somevalue";
  });

  it("should be somevalue", async ()=> {
    await result;
    expect(result).toBe("somevalue");
  })
});
```

Comment: What is the context of `this` in your unit tests? The component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this Angular?

Try using the callback (done) function:

```
describe("This is a test", ()=> {
  beforeEach(async (done)=> {
    this.result = await "somevalue";
    done();
  })

  it("should be somevalue", async ()=> {
    await this.result;
    expect(this.result).toBe("somevalue")
  })
});
```

I find this weird because I don't know what the value of `this` is.

Why are we `await`ing "somevalue", it is a string, nothing asynchronous about it but hopefully the `done` function can help you.

Comment: So the value of 'this' in Jasmine documentation is effectively a variable that can be passed between the before and after functions and still used in the it() methods. As per the h3 header called "The this keyword" [here](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/your_first_suite)